# I want to have exactly 12.5 mm between my figures/tikz figures. How do I do this?

Tags: overleaf, tikz-trees, graphs, figure-placement

For a project I am supposed to draw different graphs with edges and vertices. One of the points of the project is that the distance between the graphs should exactly be 12.5 mm, but I can't find a way at all to make this possible. I already tried several things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];

\draw (4.25, 0) -- (7.25, 0);
\draw (4.95,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (4.95,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (6.55,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (6.55,0) circle [radius=0.05];

\draw (8.5, 0) --  (11.5,0);
\draw (9.2,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (9.2,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (10.8,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (10.8,0) circle [radius=0.05];

\draw (12.75, 0) -- (15.75, 0);
\draw (13.45,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (13.45,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (15.05,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (15.05,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

However, I also need to be able to write a caption below it. Then I tried to make them into several figures, subfigures, I tried to use minipage, but all seem to result in the inability to make sure there is exactly 12.5 mm between the graphs. How do I solve this? And is there also a way to make sure there is 12.5 mm between the graphs vertically? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sub-captions are created by using four empty 3cm-wide `\subcaptionbox`es, separated by 1.25cm horizontal spacing, just like how the four pieces of drawings in `tikzpicture` are arranged.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{graphicx} % loaded by tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{positioning} % not used in this example
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\mypic{
      \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
      % do you really need draw _and_ fill, or just fill?
      \draw[fill] (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05]
        node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small] {0};
      \draw[fill] (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05]
        node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small] {1};
    }

    \mypic
    \tikzset{xshift=4.25cm}
    \mypic
    \tikzset{xshift=4.25cm}
    \mypic
    \tikzset{xshift=4.25cm}
    \mypic
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % adjust vertical spacing
  \par\vspace{-5pt}
  % emulate the width of each drawing and the separation between them
  \subcaptionbox{A}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
  \subcaptionbox{B}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
  \subcaptionbox{C}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
  \subcaptionbox{D}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}%

  \caption{Title}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This one shows the `tikzpicture` and `\subcaptionbox`es are indeed aligned, using four "X"'s as marks:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It was really helpful! Is there also a way to put the lines in the beginning of the page? The idea is to have like 12 or 16 graphs eventually on one page with spacing of 12.5 mm.

Answer (score 3):

This demonstrates how to use scopes to move the origin locally.

While it is important to specify the width of the subcaptions, it only has to be accurate if you need to wrap the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\begin{scope}[shift=(origin), local bounding box=AA]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{scope}

\coordinate (offset) at ($(origin)-(AA.west)$);% location of origin relative to local bounding box
\path (AA.east) ++ (12.5mm,0) ++ (offset) coordinate (origin);

\begin{scope}[shift=(origin) ,local bounding box=BB]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{scope}

\path (BB.east) ++ (12.5mm,0) ++ (offset) coordinate (origin);

\begin{scope}[shift=(origin) ,local bounding box=CC]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{scope}

\path (CC.east) ++ (12.5mm,0) ++ (offset) coordinate (origin);

\begin{scope}[shift=(origin) ,local bounding box=DD]
\draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
\fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
\fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
\end{scope}
% show local bounding boxes
\draw[red] (AA.south west) rectangle (AA.north east)
  (BB.south west) rectangle (BB.north east)
  (CC.south west) rectangle (CC.north east)
  (DD.south west) rectangle (DD.north east);
% subcaptions
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% not strictly necessary
\path ($(AA.north east)-(AA.south west)$);
\pgfgetlastxy{\AAwidth}{\AAheight}%
\global\let\AAwidth=\AAwidth
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

%\node[above] at (current bounding box.north) {\AAwidth};
\node[below, text width=\AAwidth, inner sep=0pt] at (AA.south) {\subcaption{}};
\node[below, text width=\AAwidth, inner sep=0pt] at (BB.south) {\subcaption{}};
\node[below, text width=\AAwidth, inner sep=0pt] at (CC.south) {\subcaption{}};
\node[below, text width=\AAwidth, inner sep=0pt] at (DD.south) {\subcaption{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use four different Ti*k*Z pictures. Don't forget the `%` at the end of lines, like in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[margin=2.625cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\subcaptionbox{A}{% <--- important
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
  \fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
  \fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \draw (0,0.5) -- (3,0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}% <--- important
}\hspace{12.5mm}% <--- important
\subcaptionbox{B}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,-0.2) -- (3,-0.2);
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
  \fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
  \fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}\hspace{12.5mm}%
\subcaptionbox{C}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
  \fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
  \fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}\hspace{12.5mm}%
\subcaptionbox{D}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small]{0};
  \fill (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \draw (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05] node[above, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small]{1};
  \fill (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\caption{Global caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]